# Google listing my product as "Free" in search results

Tags: e-commerce, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have used Schema.org properties on my eCommerce site. Today I listed few new products that don't have prices yet, so listed with `$0` price.

Now Google is fetching these products as "Free" item in its [search results](https://www.google.com.au/search?espv=2&q=denon%20x2200w%20digitalcinema&oq=denon%20x2200w%20digitalcinema&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.416566.418595.0.418788.14.10.0.0.0.0.437.1096.2-3j0j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..12.2.639.FuWIF2SHySY) (find the "Digital Cinema" result and you will see "Free" attribute in result).

**What I can do?**

I can remove `price` from `itemprop="price"` but it will throw an error for my code.

Not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: I think once google reindexes your site, should be fine.

Comment: I have removed schema for those products having less than `$0`. But still seek better approach if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have a price (in which case you provide the `price` property), or you don’t (in which case you omit the `price` property).

Getting an error in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool does not necessarily mean that your code is invalid (there are no required properties in Schema.org, so having no `price` is perfectly fine). It just means that Google probably won’t display a Rich Snippet for this content. And rightly so, as you don’t have a price, so what should they display instead?

So omit the `price` property for now; add it as soon as you have the price.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but still would be better to have error less page in google webmaster tool too, since google gonna display few error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to have the display price as a string, you can set it something like "$TBD" (To Be Determined), or even "Out Of Stock". This is how I've seen some other web stores do it.

Comment: You will still get schema error, since `TBD` is not price.

Comment: Are you able change the schema, or is this a 3rd party framework you're limited by?

Comment: Yes I can change my schema.